# PostQuitMessage(0) won't terminate my 'program'

Tags: c++, windows, message-handlers

I'm just trying to learn a little bit of C++ and wrote a few lines that do nothing but open a window.
I've added a Message Handler too and by clicking the [X] on my window it closes as its supposed to.
As the next step I wanted the Program to terminate when the [X] is clicked but it does'nt do that.
Here's my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (msg){
    case WM_CLOSE:
        PostQuitMessage(88);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}


int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE pPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int cCmdShow) {

    const auto pClassName = "M3D";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { 0 };
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(wc);
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hCursor = nullptr;
    wc.hbrBackground = nullptr;
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.lpszClassName = pClassName;
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, pClassName, "Fenster M3D", WS_CAPTION | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU, 200, 200, 640, 480, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    //Fenster aufrufen
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    //

    //message Pumpe
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg,nullptr,0,0) > 0){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell my whats wrong and why my PostQuitMessage() wont do its job?
The other threads I've found werent really helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on this assignment:

`wc.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProc;`

You are telling the message loop to dispatch messages directly to `DefWindowProc()`, so your custom `WndProc()` is never used, so `PostQuitMessage()` is never called.  `DefWindowProc()` does not call `PostQuitMessage()` for any message that it processes.

Change that assignment to this instead:

`wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;`

Also, per the [Closing the Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/closing-the-window) documentation on MSDN, `DefWindowProc()` calls `DestroyWindow()` when processing `WM_CLOSE`, so you should call `PostQuitMessage()` in reply to `WM_DESTROY` instead:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (msg){
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(88);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```